# MapReduce job fails with ExitCodeException exitCode=1

Tags: python, hadoop, mapreduce

I have run into this issue running a mapreduce job:

```
19/02/25 03:06:41 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1551092767354_0001 failed with state FAILED due to: Application application_1551092767354_0001 failed 2 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1551092767354_0001_000002 exited with  exitCode: 1
For more detailed output, check application tracking page:http://quickstart.cloudera:8088/proxy/application_1551092767354_0001/Then, click on links to logs of each attempt.
Diagnostics: Exception from container-launch.
Container id: container_1551092767354_0001_02_000001
Exit code: 1
Stack trace: ExitCodeException exitCode=1: 
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:538)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:455)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:715)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.launchContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:211)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:302)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:82)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I have tried manually adding yarn classpath to the yarn-site.xml but it didn't work. Does anyone have a solution? Thank you.

Edit: This is the log of the error, but I'm not sure what it means:

> ERROR [main]
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.jobhistory.JobHistoryEventHandler: Failed
>   checking for the existance of history intermediate done directory:
>   [hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/history/done_intermediate]
>   2019-02-25 03:06:36,034 INFO [main]
>   org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService: Service
>   JobHistoryEventHandler failed in state INITED; cause:
>   org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnRuntimeException:
>   org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Permission denied:
>   user=cloudera, access=WRITE,
>   inode="/user/history":mapred:hadoop:drwxr-xr-x    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.DefaultAuthorizationProvider.checkFsPermission(DefaultAuthorizationProvider.java:257)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.DefaultAuthorizationProvider.check(DefaultAuthorizationProvider.java:238)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.DefaultAuthorizationProvider.check(DefaultAuthorizationProvider.java:216)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.DefaultAuthorizationProvider.checkPermission(DefaultAuthorizationProvider.java:145)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.checkPermission(FSPermissionChecker.java:138)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.checkPermission(FSNamesystem.java:6596)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.checkPermission(FSNamesystem.java:6578)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.checkAncestorAccess(FSNamesystem.java:6530)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.mkdirsInternal(FSNamesystem.java:4334)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.mkdirsInt(FSNamesystem.java:4304)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.mkdirs(FSNamesystem.java:4277)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.mkdirs(NameNodeRpcServer.java:852)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.AuthorizationProviderProxyClientProtocol.mkdirs(AuthorizationProviderProxyClientProtocol.java:321)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.mkdirs(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:601)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:619)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:1060)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2044)  at
>   org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2040)  at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1671)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2038)

Comment: `For more detailed output, check application tracking page:http://quickstart.cloudera:8088/proxy/application_1551092767354_0001/Then, click on links to logs of each attempt.`

Comment: I have edited my post above with the log of the error but I don't understand, do you have any idea?